# How do I set the contentType using Malsup jquery Form plugin?

Tags: jquery, utf-8, multipartform-data

I have form that includes a file input element. When I make a request to the server, Firebug reports the following in the request headers:

```
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------287452692419072
```

However, I set the content type as follows:

```
   var setupOptions = { 
            success: update,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',            
            url:   '../update.html',
            contentType: 'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8',
            error: error.handle,
            timeout: 50000
    };                
    $('#form').ajaxSubmit(setupOptions);
```

When the user enters data such as the following into a form element

```
sellers’
```

the data gets stored in the database as

```
 sellersâ
```

I believe this is because the browser is not sending the request as charset=UTF-8. How can I set the charset=UTF-8? I would prefer to keep using this plugin if possible.

**EDIT**

In case the issue is not in the browser or I need to implement a workaround on the server, here's some additional information:

I'm using Java 1.6, SQL Server, Maven, myBatis 3 and Spring 3.0 (using MVC annotations).

Answer (score 0):

aw the horror of ie... you need to return a ResponseEntity in your servlet with a header. 
something like:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/somefile/add", method = RequestMethod.POST) {
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadTempImage(
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
return new ResponseEntity("horses on a boat", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```